# How can I call a specific AMI into the JUJU charm for deploying the infrastructure in JUJU?

Tags: juju, aws

We had the pre-configured AMIs of our machines which need to be called through the JUJU charm to spin up the instances. Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

You are very much working against the Juju tool by customizing images and creating AMIs.  There is no way to easily deploy this with modern Juju.  You might be able to do it by creating and hosting a custom stream endpoint, but it's not the design, and it would be a lot of work.

Juju deploys reference images [produced by Canonical](https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com), and makes modifications on top.  The modifications are codified in something called **charms**.  Instead of using a customized image workflow, your service should be fully modeled as a set of charms, hopefully connecting with other charms that already exist, like `postgresql`, `haproxy` or `apache2`.

I don't say this to imply that an image based workflow is crazy.  In fact, customized docker-images are the building blocks of Kubernetes applications, but it's why you are not finding out how to do what you are asking with Juju.

### References

- https://jujucharms.com/how-it-works
- https://jujucharms.com/docs/stable/charms